# Change permalinks for specific pages

Tags: permalinks, urls

How can I change permalinks for selected pages? For example, static page will be like this

```
example.com
```

other sub pages will be

```
example.com/postname/
```

Right now I can't achieve what I want with static page. Static page look like this

```
example.com/postname/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one page at example.com so let's say you have an 'about' page: example.com/about
In Wordpress Settings > Reading Settings you can select a static page to be the homepage, so example.com would now show the 'about' page.

Now, go to Wordpress Settings > Permalinks and select Post name.

Comment: It show pls look at my page 

http://www.elefantti.iq.pl/

I have multilanugal site , and on both static pages in polish and english i have /postname/ in the end of permalink and for those page's i dont want that

Comment: You should have mentioned that you're using a multilingual plugin - this completely changes the game, and puts the question off-topic (3rd party).

Comment: Yes i using multilangual plugin polylang , do you know how solve this problem?

I will be very thankfull for this .